# VBA- Using inputbox to filter and copy data

Tags: vba, excel

i am working on a userform where i puted a button that when i click on it i got an input box where i try to filter data of the  column (E) then after filtering this data  copy  from colum A1 till the value filtered in the column E in another sheet caaled filtred_data  i am using this code this code but it show me a bug dont nw how to fix it

```
Private Sub CommandButton9_Click()
Dim xno As Integer, Found As Range
Do
    xno = Application.InputBox("Enter the number of Top communities ", Type:=1)
    If TypeName(xno) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    Set Found = Columns("E").Find(what:=xno, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Found Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "the number was not found, please try again !!", vbInformation
    Else
        Found.Range("A1:F10000").Copy Destination:=Sheets("filtred_data").Range("A1:F10000")
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

if anyone can help me please , thank you

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Also, you mention that your sheet is `filtered_data`, yet your code shows `filtred_data`

Comment: the error i am getting is run-time error 9  subscript out of range

Comment: about the name of the sheet just writhed it wrong my fault :D

Comment: you declare `xno` as integer, yet checks whether `xno` is a boolean??

Comment: why not just declare `xno` as variant

Comment: did so but still have the same error :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case is that you are setting the `Found` variable to be a single cell by using the `Find` method. Later in your code, you are trying to copy the `A1:F10000` of that ONE cell when you write `Found.Range("A1:F1000")`.

Essentially, your code looks like this (assume `Found` refers to cell `E25`):

```
Range("E25").Range("A1:F1000").Copy
```

Can you see why that would cause an error?

I'd try to offer more help, but it's hard to determine exactly what you want. Can you possibly give more details about your spreadsheet layouts and an example of what you want to happen?

Comment: yes you are right , 

in the sheet that i am filtering i have 5 column but i want to filter just by the last column which is column E  so after clicking on the button to filter i need to copy all column from A to E but only the filtered data   to the new sheet "filtred_data"